# How can I disable/gray out dropdown selection checkboxes for two records available in setSubmittedNominees state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can I `disable/gray` out dropdown selection checkboxes for two records available in a state `setSubmittedNominees` in react hooks ? I tried to pass into submittedNominees into selectedValues and disablePreSelectedValues(true) but it doesn't work that way can someone please advise on this ?
codesandbox link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-haslett-s0oeh?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import Axios from "axios";
import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import Multiselect from "multiselect-react-dropdown";

const options = [
  { id: 1, name: "Ath", email: "ath.best@test1.com", access: null },
  { id: 2, name: "Arnolds", email: "arnold@test1.com", access: null },
  { id: 3, name: "Alter", email: "alloop@test1.com", access: null },
  { id: 4, name: "Brandan", email: "brandan@test1.com", access: null },
  { id: 5, name: "Ron", email: "ron@test1.com", access: null },
  { id: 6, name: "Rads", email: "rad@test1.com", access: null },
  { id: 7, name: "Sam", email: "sam@y.com", access: null }
];

const submitted = [
  { id: 4, name: "Brandan", email: "brandan@test1.com", access: null },
  { id: 5, name: "Ron", email: "ron@test1.com", access: null }
];
const Selection= () => {
  const [option, setOption] = useState([]);
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState([]);
  const [nomRegister, setNomRegister] = useState([{}]);
  const [helperText, setHelperText] = useState("");
  const [userEmail, setUserEmail] = useState("");
  const [submittedNominees, setSubmittedNominees] = useState([{}]);
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors },
    reset
  } = useForm();
  const maxOptions = 3;
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    const userEmail = localStorage.getItem("loginEmail");
    setUserEmail(userEmail);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await Axios.get(
          "http://localhost:8000/service/nomineeslist"
        );
        //const data1 = res.data;
        setOption(options);
        console.log("Get the list of nominees :" + JSON.stringify(res.data));
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        // const res = await Axios.get(
        //   "http://localhost:8000/service/submittednominees"
        // );
        setSubmittedNominees(submitted);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const handleTypeSelect = (e, i) => {
    const copy = [...selectedOption];
    copy.push(e[i]);
    setSelectedOption(copy);
  };

  const sendNomination = () => {
    console.log("What the Array holds: " + JSON.stringify(nomRegister));
    const fetchData = async (nomRegister) => {
      try {
        const res = await Axios.post(
          "http://localhost:8000/service/nominateperson",
          { userEmail },
          nomRegister
        );
        if (res.data) {
          console.log("Print data:" + res.data);
          const successMessage = res.data.message;
          setHelperText(successMessage);
          setNomRegister(reset);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        setNomRegister(reset);
        setHelperText(e.message);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  };

  options.forEach((option) => {
    option.displayValue = option.name + "\t" + option.email;
    submittedNominees.forEach((item) => {
      let subEmail = item.email; // how can I pass those two email to selectedValues and make it  disable ?
    });
  });

  const handleChange = (e, i) => {
    const { name, email, value } = e.target;

    // immutating state (best practice)
    const updateList = nomRegister.map((item) => {
      return { ...item };
    });

    const select_Email = selectedOption.map((item) => {
      return item.email;
    });

    //change the specific array case depends on the id //email:emailList[i],
    updateList[i] = {
      ...updateList[i],
      name: name,
      email: select_Email[i],
      reason: value
    };
    setNomRegister(updateList);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Nominate a person</h1>
      <div className="nomineeSelectBox">
        <div id="dialog2" className="triangle_down1" />
        <div className="arrowdown">
          <Multiselect
            onSelect={(e) => handleTypeSelect(e, selectedOption.length)}
            options={selectedOption.length + 1 === maxOptions ? [] : options}
            displayValue="displayValue"
            selectedValues={subEmail}
            showCheckbox={true}
            emptyRecordMsg={"Maximum nominees selected !"}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="nominationcount"></div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(sendNomination)}>
        <div className="nomineesSelectedList">
          <h4>Selected Nominees</h4>
          {selectedOption.map((x, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
              <div className="row eachrecord">
                <div className="column">
                  <label className="nomlabel">
                    {x?.name} <b>>></b>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <input
                  required
                  type="textarea"
                  placeholder="Please provide reason for nomination.."
                  key={i}
                  id={i}
                  name={x?.name}
                  className="nomineechoosed"
                  onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, i)}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}

          <div className="row">
            <div className="buttongroup">
              <input id="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
              <input id="Cancel" type="button" value="Cancel" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
      <span className="nominationValidationText">{helperText}</span>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Selection;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the **issue** here is that you are showing your dropdown selection checkboxes by **displayValue** (`displayValue="displayValue"`) and your `submitted` array that you you will assign to `submittedNominees` (`setSubmittedNominees(submitted)`) **does not** contain `displayValue`:

```
const submitted = [
  { id: 4, name: "Brandan", email: "brandan@test1.com", access: null },
  { id: 5, name: "Ron", email: "ron@test1.com", access: null }
];
```

**Solution:**:

1. Make your `submitted` for example like this:

```
const submitted = [
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Brandan",
    email: "brandan@test1.com",
    access: null,
    displayValue: "Brandan  brandan@test1.com"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "Ron",
    email: "ron@test1.com",
    access: null,
    displayValue: "Ron  ron@test1.com"
  }
];
```

2. Add `selectedValues={submittedNominees}` to your `Multiselect` to find out which values you will disable:

```
<Multiselect
  onSelect={(e) => handleTypeSelect(e, selectedOption.length)}
  options={selectedOption.length + 1 === maxOptions ? [] : options}
  displayValue="displayValue"
  disablePreSelectedValues={true}
  selectedValues={submittedNominees}
  showCheckbox={true}
  emptyRecordMsg={"Maximum nominees selected !"}
/>
```

Codesandbox [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-wind-jnnkm?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank you but something is not working in real example...

Comment: All good fixed now...I have accepted and upvoted

Comment: One issue noted in the codesandbox link if I try to select one more record it still console log the pre selected  one.. the new one selected is not getting outputted..

Comment: The `handleTypeSelect ` is getting wrong i think... when i set a break point it is not showing  the selected data

Comment: Yes, I noticed. There is another problem, if there are preselected options, you can select more than 3 options. Of course, this will happen because the preselected options are not adapted to the old code, so we have to modify our functions to handle it.

Comment: Any idea how can we animate records from bottom to top >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69086376/how-can-we-animate-the-display-of-records-using-react-spring