# How can we animate the display of records using react-spring

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-spring

How can we animate the display of records using `react-spring`. Can we call  the `useTransition` in useEffect() ? I would like to animate records from bottom to top one by one when user navigate to the page. I have tried below nothing is happening..? Any advise would be really helpful.

https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-snowflake-34dpx?file=/src/App.js:711-881

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useTransition, animated } from "react-spring";

import "./styles.css";

const array1 = [
  { id: "1", name: "Cat" },
  { id: "2", name: "Dog" },
  { id: "3", name: "Cow" }
];
export default function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState(array1);
  const height = 20;
  useEffect(() => {
    setList(array1);
  }, []);

  const transitions = useTransition(
    Object.entries(list).map((data, i) => ({ ...data, y: i * height })),
    {
      from: { position: "absolute", opacity: 0 },
      enter: { height: 0, opacity: 1 },
      leave: { opacity: 0 },
      config: { tension: 220, friction: 120 }
    }
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* {Object.entries(list).map((item, index) => (
        <div key={item.id} className="record">
          <span key={item.name}>{item.name}</span>
        </div>
      ))} */}

      {Object.entries(transitions).map(({ item, props, key }) => (
        <animated.div key={key} style={{ ...props, position: "absolute" }}>
          <div key={item.id} className="record">
            <span key={item.name}>{item.name}</span>
          </div>
        </animated.div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `transitions` variable is a function, so you don't want `Object.entries(transitions).map()`.  It's not an error because functions in Javascript are also objects, but it's not going to do anything because the array of entries is an empty array.

You want to call the `transitions` function, which is its own sort of mapper.

```
{transitions((props, item, key) => (
```

---

Well now I'm seeing a cyan box instead of a white screen.  So that's a little progress, but there's more to do.

If you `console.log` your `item` object you'll see that it doesn't look right.

```
Object.entries(list).map((data, i) => ({ ...data, y: i * height }))
```

You are mapping an array of **object entries**, so the `data` variable is an array containing the key and the value.  You don't want that.  `list` is already an array, so ditch the `Object.entries`.

```
list.map((data, i) => ({ ...data, y: i * height })),
```

---

Now I see "Cow"!  But the other two are hidden because your items are appearing on top of each other.

You are using absolute positioning but you haven't passed the position down to the component.  Since you aren't animating that value, it's a property of `item` rather than `props`.

```
<animated.div key={key} style={{ ...props, position: "absolute", top: item.y }}>
```

---

Now I see all three!

But the overlapping background blocks are probably not what you intended.  I'm not sure what you intended, really, because you have a `height` of `20` in your JS and `100px` in your CSS.  You also have a `height` property in your animation but it's not doing anything.

All of your list items have `height: 0px` because you are setting the height to `0` in the `enter` property, which is called when an item first enters the list.  On the other hand, the `from` property sets the initial values that the item animates away from, so maybe you want to have an initial value of `height: 0` in `from` and some final value of `height` in `enter`.

You can animate the height of the background, but that won't impact the height of the text.  You might want a `transform` like `scaleY`. You can use a transform instead of the height animation (all items start out in their final position and grow in place) or alongside the height animation (all items start together at the top and grow down).

---

Here's one possible effect: [Code Sandbox Link](https://6fywd.csb.app/)

style.css

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
.record {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: aqua;
  margin: 20px 0;
  color: #1f1d1d;
}
.title {
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 35px;
}
```

App.js

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useTransition, animated } from "react-spring";

import "./styles.css";

const array1 = [
  { id: "1", name: "Cat" },
  { id: "2", name: "Dog" },
  { id: "3", name: "Cow" }
];

export default function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState(array1);

  const transitions = useTransition(list, {
    from: { opacity: 0, scaleY: 0 },
    enter: { opacity: 1, scaleY: 1 },
    leave: { opacity: 0 },
    config: { tension: 220, friction: 120 }
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {transitions((props, item, key) => {
        console.log(props, item, key);
        return (
          <animated.div key={key} style={{ ...props }} className="record">
            <div className="title">{item.name}</div>
          </animated.div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

**Edit**

As requested, from the bottom to the top one after another:

```
export default function App() {
  const height = window.innerHeight;

  const [list, setList] = useState(array1);

  const transitions = useTransition(list, {
    from: { opacity: 0, translateY: height },
    enter: { opacity: 1, translateY: 0 },
    leave: { opacity: 0 },
    config: { tension: 220, friction: 120 },
    trail: 200
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {transitions((props, item, key) => {
        console.log(props, item, key);
        return (
          <animated.div key={key} style={{ ...props }} className="record">
            <div className="title">{item.name}</div>
          </animated.div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: ..Thank you very much, can something moving form bottom of the page towards top ..one after the other...is that possible ?

Comment: Yes, but it might require knowing the height of the document?.  You can use an absolute position or a translateY transform for the movement.  For "one after the other" you can use the `trail` property.